# Insert Into T2 all rows from T1 that are currently not in T2

Tags: sql-server, left-join, sql-insert

I am trying to insert all records from T1 into T2 that are not currently in T2

I have tried in a loop as I am generating a code from a stored proc as the identifier of T2

```
declare     @Part           VARCHAR(255),
            @GenValue       VARCHAR(255),
            @x              INT
set @x = (select count(*) from T1)  
WHILE @x >=0

BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[usp_GenInd] @GenValue OUT,@GencCode = 'TKM', @GencIncrement = 1


     set @Part = @GencValue

    INSERT INTO dbo.T2
    SELECT  @Part                           AS  [part],
            [Prod_Code] + Column_Header     AS  [identifier],
            [part_rev]                      =   NULL,
            '!'                             AS  [u_version],
            a.[Descr]                           AS  [descr],
            GETDATE()                       AS  [last_updated],
            'ME'                            AS  [last_upd_user],
            'EA'                            AS  [basic_unit],
            [source]                        =   NULL,
            'MAIN'                          AS  [level_1],
            'GROUP'                         AS  [level_2],
            'ME'                            AS  [user_created],
            '20'                            AS  [status],
            [Prod_Code]                     AS  [master_part],
            [drawing_no]                    =   NULL

    FROM [dbo].T1 a
    LEFT JOIN dbo.T2 b
        ON a.Prod_Code + a.Column_Header = b.part
    WHERE b.part is null

END
```

I keep getting error saying primary key violation on T2 which is the @part variable I am generating from the stored proc.

really slow as well, I thought an insert on left join on null was quicker than a cursor.

only have 67 rows in T1

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Why do you need to generate this value in a stored procedure? Since your design requires you to call a stored procedure to generate part of your primary key you are stuck. I have to say, that is not a very good design choice.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange, a simpler design should eliminate key violations.  As for the general idea of inserting records that dont already exist, I suggest the MERGE command.  Super fast and designed for something just like this.  I am not sure it will work and did not post an answer because without specifics on table design and use case(s) its too hard to guess what  you are trying to do 'big picture'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - go back to the cursor if you must continue to use this stored procedure to generate primary key values. The logic error you added to this script is the insert statement. It does not select a specific row from T1 - it selects all rows in T1 that do not exist in T2 (assuming that logic is correct - I'm not going to evaluate it). Presumably you must call the procedure usp_GenInd to generate a PK value for each row in T1. In addition, you never decrement @x - so you have an endless loop.

And notice the wording - "not exists". Generally I find it easier to understand undocumented logic when the query matches (as close as possible) the intent of the code. Your left join logic is the same as not exists - just more difficult to figure out. And you also have a potential problem with your concatenation logic to check for existence. 'AA' + 'B' = 'A' + 'AB' - but the columns contain different values. Be careful about assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT  your needed data
 FROM [dbo].T1
 EXCEPT
 SELECT  already existing data
 FROM [dbo].T2
)
INSERT INTO dbo.T2
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thank you all for your advise, 

Unfortunately I am unable to generate the primary key code for T2 in any other way, its a code generated by a piece of software that looks after all parts, I need to get the next number in the sequence from this proc.

Comment: I will look into the merge as I think that might be the best way forward, the CTE wouldnt work as I wouldn't be able to generate the T2 primary key using a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN logic is flawed.

In your INSERT you have this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T2
SELECT  @Part                           AS  [part],
        [Prod_Code] + Column_Header     AS  [identifier],
```

Inserting @Part into [part]

But when you do your JOIN to rule out existing rows, you have this:

```
   LEFT JOIN dbo.T2 b
        ON a.Prod_Code + a.Column_Header = b.part
```

To rule out existing rows, you should be joining on `@part=b.part`.